# How do I keep first method call on the same line with a fluent formatter for vscode with java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, fluent, method-chaining

I found [these formatter settings](https://github.com/snjeza/vscode-test/blob/master/fluent.xml) looking for a vscode fluent formatter. That can be set with the following vscode-java setting
`"java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snjeza/vscode-test/master/fluent.xml"`
It seems that all fluent method calls will be proceeded by a new line. My expectation for a single method call is that it would remain on the same line.

Consider a simple method. My expectation would be:

```java
public static String cleanText(String text) {
  return text.replace("@#!£", "");
```

But what actually happens upon formatting is:

```java
public static String cleanText(String text) {
  return text
      .replace("@#!£", "");
}
```

For a longer method chain my expectation would be

```java
public void method() {
  variable.myMethod()
      .anotherMethod()
      .somethingElse();
}
```

Is this change possible with the eclipse formatter?

I am aware there are several other related questions, **but none of them address this specific issue of wrapping method chains with the exception of the first call.**

Answer (score 0):

Download the `fluent.xml` locally and change the configuration `join_wrapped_lines` to `false`:

```
<setting id="org.eclipse.jdt.core.formatter.join_wrapped_lines" value="false"/>
```

In Settings.json, set

```
"java.format.settings.url": "\the absolute path to fluent.xml\"
```

Right click and choose **Format Document**:

[image]

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately I get the same behaviour as described in the question.  It doesn't move the single method call onto the same line.

Comment: Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace**, then delete the `"java.format.settings.url"` and rewrite it to settings.json because vscode will read the `fluent.xml` to cache, so if you edit it but not rewrite to settings.json, extension would still use the previous formatting style in cache, not the new edited one.

Comment: Still the same behaviour unfortunately. This is on vscode 1.55.0 with vscode-java 0.76.0

Comment: I'm using **Java Extension Pack**, don't know vscode-java. When you set `"java.format.settings.url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/snjeza/vscode-test/master/fluent.xml"`, the object.method() was split to different lines. then download the fluent.xml locally and set the configuration `"join_wrapped_lines" value="false"`, then save the .xml. Set `"java.format.settings.url": "\the absolute path to fluent.xml\"`, then turn to the .java file, right click and choose **format document**, I've test it in other machines, and it works normally. Show me your settings.

Comment: vscode-java is the java language support extension, which is found in the extension pack. (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java)

Here are my settings, https://gist.github.com/itsHobbes/86abc70f117b184bada2f0be538058ed#file-settings-json-L172

Line 172 is where I have the fluent.xml set as the formatter, as you described in your original answer. I've also put that in the gist too.

Comment: That's weird. Is there anything wrong to the path of fluent.xml?  right click the fulent.xml and copy its location. Or something wrong with file extension? Open it in file explorer, view-> file name extensions.

Comment: Or try to reinstall the java extension.

Comment: No the path is fine, if I use the fluent formatter it does work, it just doesn't keep the nice single line as shown in the gif you posted.